# Monthly rollover system

Tags: python, sql, mysql

I have learned a little Python for a few projects at work. This is my first *finished* application and I was hoping someone would take a look at it. I would love some tips on the mistakes I've made.

```
################################################################################
#Monthly Rollover System                                                       #
#Written by Ryan Hanson 2012                                                   #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################

#Python Imports
import sys

#PyQt4 Imports
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql #@UnusedImport

#UI Imports
from main import Ui_MainWindow
from popup import Ui_Dialog

#Variables
dbhost = "192.168.1.39"
dbname = "material"
dbuser = "fab"
dbpswd = "doylefab"

#This Runs First
class launch(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        #Prepare the first window 
        self.main = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main.setupUi(self)

        #Set the icon and select the first tab
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons/main.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("Material Tracking")
        self.main.tabs.setCurrentIndex(0)

        #Make db accessible to the whole app - I am not sure this is the best way to do this?
        global db
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL");

        #Host name and Database
        db.setHostName(dbhost)
        db.setDatabaseName(dbname)
        db.setUserName(dbuser)
        db.setPassword(dbpswd)
        ok = db.open()

        #ok is true if the database can be connected to
        if ok:
            self.materialQuery = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
            materialdata = "select id, material, d1, d2, d3 from material_tbl"
            if self.materialQuery.exec_(materialdata):
                self.materialchange(1)

                #Set the range for the slider so all records can be navigated to.
                self.main.horizontalSlider.setRange(1, self.materialQuery.size())

                self.main.modelMaterial = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
                self.main.modelMaterial.setTable("inventory_view")
                self.main.modelMaterial.select()
                self.main.tableMaterial.setModel(self.main.modelMaterial)

                #Is there a better way to set columns?
                self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(0, 50)
                self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
                self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(2, 75)
                self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(3, 100)
                self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(4, 100)
                self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(5, 100)

#########CONNECTIONS###############################################################################
            self.main.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.materialchange)            
            self.main.tableMaterial.doubleClicked.connect(self.dblclickMaterial)            
            self.main.lineSearch.textChanged.connect(self.filterMaterial)          
            self.main.buttonReceive.clicked.connect(self.received)
            self.main.buttonUsed.clicked.connect(self.used)

#########END IF THE CONNECTION FAILS###############################################################
        else:
            self.dberror()

    def materialchange(self, index):
        if db.isOpen():
            #Seek to the next record and load the proper data
            self.materialQuery.seek(index-1)

            mat = self.materialQuery.value(0).toString()
            self.main.lineId.setText(mat)
            self.main.lineMaterial.setText(self.materialQuery.value(1).toString())
            self.main.lined1.setText(self.materialQuery.value(2).toString())
            self.main.lined2.setText(self.materialQuery.value(3).toString())
            self.main.lined3.setText(self.materialQuery.value(4).toString())

            self.main.modelreceived = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
            self.main.modelreceived.setTable("received_tbl")
            self.main.modelreceived.setFilter('mat_id = {0}'.format(mat))
            self.main.modelreceived.select()
            self.main.tablereceived.setModel(self.main.modelreceived)

            #Is there a better way to set columns?
            self.main.tablereceived.setColumnWidth(0, 50)
            self.main.tablereceived.setColumnWidth(1, 50)
            self.main.tablereceived.setColumnWidth(2, 75)
            self.main.tablereceived.setColumnWidth(3, 125)
            self.main.tablereceived.setColumnWidth(4, 125)

            self.main.modelused = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
            self.main.modelused.setTable("used_tbl")
            self.main.modelused.setFilter('mat_id = {0}'.format(mat))
            self.main.modelused.select()
            self.main.tableused.setModel(self.main.modelused)

            #Is there a better way to set columns?
            self.main.tableused.setColumnWidth(0, 50)
            self.main.tableused.setColumnWidth(1, 50)
            self.main.tableused.setColumnWidth(2, 75)
            self.main.tableused.setColumnWidth(3, 125)
            self.main.tableused.setColumnWidth(4, 125)
        else:
            self.dberror()

    def dblclickMaterial(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        kid = self.main.modelMaterial.data(self.main.modelMaterial.index(row, 0)).toString()
        i=0
        self.materialQuery.seek(i)

        #This is probably a relatively slow way to find the right record. Any suggestions?
        while self.materialQuery.value(0).toString() <> kid:
            i+=1
            self.materialQuery.seek(i)

        self.materialchange(i+1)
        self.main.tabs.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.main.horizontalSlider.setSliderPosition(i+1)

    def filterMaterial(self):
        r=0
        R=self.main.modelMaterial.rowCount()
        c=0
        C=self.main.modelMaterial.columnCount()
        s=0
        search = str(self.main.lineSearch.text())
        #Loop though all columns on all rows and hide rows where none of the columns match the search term.
        while r < R:
            while c<C:
                if search.lower() not in str(self.main.modelMaterial.data(self.main.modelMaterial.index(r, c)).toString()).lower():
                    s += 1
                c += 1
            if s==C:
                self.main.tableMaterial.setRowHidden(r, True)
            else:
                self.main.tableMaterial.setRowHidden(r, False)
            c=0
            r +=1
            s=0

    def received(self):
        def accept():
            mat = self.main.lineId.text()
            qty = self.popup.dialog.lineQty.text()
            notes = self.popup.dialog.lineNotes.text()
            insertQuery = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
            #There are two tables used to track material, one that records details about each load we receive and the other that keeps a running total of what we should have on hand.
            insertdata = "INSERT INTO `material`.`received_tbl` (`id`, `mat_id`, `quantity`, `date`, `note`) VALUES (NULL, {0}, {1}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '{2}');".format(mat, qty, notes)
            if insertQuery.exec_(insertdata):
                inventoryQuery=QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
                inventorydata = "Update inventory_tbl set quantity = (quantity + {0}) where mat_id = {1}".format(qty, mat)
                if inventoryQuery.exec_(inventorydata):
                    print("{0} Received.".format(qty))
                    self.main.modelMaterial.select()
                    if self.main.lineSearch <> "":
                        self.filterMaterial()
                else:
                    print(inventoryQuery.lastError().text()) 
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Fail...", 'There was a problem and this operation did not complete...')                   
            else:
                print(insertQuery.lastError().text())
                QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Fail...", 'There was a problem and this operation did not complete...')

        self.popup = QtGui.QDialog()
        self.popup.show()
        self.popup.dialog = Ui_Dialog()
        self.popup.dialog.setupUi(self.popup)
        self.popup.setWindowTitle("Received")
        self.popup.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons/main.png"))

        self.popup.dialog.buttonBox.accepted.connect(accept)

    #Almost exactly the same as received but it updates the used table and subtracts from the total.
    def used(self):
        def accept():
            mat = self.main.lineId.text()
            qty = self.popup.dialog.lineQty.text()
            notes = self.popup.dialog.lineNotes.text()
            insertQuery = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
            insertdata = "INSERT INTO `material`.`used_tbl` (`id`, `mat_id`, `quantity`, `date`, `note`) VALUES (NULL, {0}, {1}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '{2}');".format(mat, qty, notes)
            if insertQuery.exec_(insertdata):
                inventoryQuery=QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
                inventorydata = "Update inventory_tbl set quantity = (quantity - {0}) where mat_id = {1}".format(qty, mat)
                if inventoryQuery.exec_(inventorydata):
                    print("{0} Used.".format(qty))
                    self.main.modelMaterial.select()
                    if self.main.lineSearch <> "":
                        self.filterMaterial()
                else:
                    print(inventoryQuery.lastError().text())
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Fail...", 'There was a problem and this operation did not complete...')
            else:
                print(insertQuery.lastError().text())
                QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Fail...", 'There was a problem and this operation did not complete...')

        self.popup = QtGui.QDialog()
        self.popup.show()
        self.popup.dialog = Ui_Dialog()
        self.popup.dialog.setupUi(self.popup)
        self.popup.setWindowTitle("Used")
        self.popup.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons/main.png"))

        self.popup.dialog.buttonBox.accepted.connect(accept)

    #Called when the database encounters a connection problem.
    def dberror(self):
        print(db.lastError().text())
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Fail...", 'Could not connect...')
        sys.exit()

    #This is in place to unload material query.
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("Unloading Material Query...")
        self.materialQuery.finish()
        print("Have a nice day!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = launch()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you had better change your Database username and password.  that is my first review

Answer (score 3):

Some really obvious stuff popped up in a casual pylint check over your code. As well as some further, more advanced ideas for changing your code below.

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

The semi-colon is not necessary in python.

```
while self.materialQuery.value(0).toString() <> kid:
if self.main.lineSearch <> "":
if self.main.lineSearch <> "":
```

The <> operator is frowned upon, and is going to be removed. Your code will not be forwards-compatible.

```
r=0
R=self.main.modelMaterial.rowCount()
c=0
C=self.main.modelMaterial.columnCount()
s=0
s==C:
c<C:
```

PEP8 standard specifies that you have to have spaces before and after assignment, equality and comparison operators, among others. You're not getting any benefit if you scrunch stuff up like that. This isn't C.

```
#Is there a better way to set columns?
self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(0, 50)
self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(2, 75)
self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(3, 100)
self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(4, 100)
self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(5, 100)
```

Yes, it's called a loop. Such as:

```
COL_WIDTHS_CONST = {
  0: 50,
  1: 200,
  2: 75,
  3: 100,
  4: 100,
  5: 100,
}
def set_widths(self, colDict):
    for column in colDict:
        self.main.tableMaterial.setColumnWidth(column , colDict[column])

# Somewhere in your init code:
self.set_widths(self, COL_WIDTHS_CONST):
```

Move stuff out of your init method. Even if all the magic happens in the init method, you can't put all the low-level code there. Make separate functions. e.g.

1. SetupMainWindow
2. SetupDatabase
3. GetMaterialData (From the database)
4. ConnectEvents
5. ConfigureGUIElements (You put your column/row width setting code here)

The fact that you had so many comments in your giant 40 line init method should be telling of the fact that it was doing too much in one spot, and you had to use comments to divide it into separate groupings.

Another thing I noticed. You seem to be mixing your data retrieval, presentation and control logic all in the same pieces of code. You should move code out into separate functions. If you have a method that is more than a few lines, then odds are it does too much, or it repeats.

Move the SQL code out of your code, and into constants. It makes making changes to your SQL a little more manageable.

One last thing. It's something I see often with sloppy coders that don't use a proper IDE for python development. Trailing whitespace.

Comment: Hey thanks for the write up! I made a lot off mistakes in this piece of code. Lots of the things you suggested I fix, I don't do any more. Thank you for taking the time to look at it.